# "docker run" fails with "-v" options on CentOS6.5

Tags: centos, docker, mesos, centos6.5, mesosphere

### Summary

I'm trying to set up Mesos cluster using Docker containers.

But `docker run` command fails with `-v` volume options, and succeeds without volume options.

Message is as follows,

```
FATA[0008] Error response from daemon: No such image: redjack/mesos-master:latest (tag: latest)
```

despite the image `redjack/mesos-master:latest` exists.

It's strange that adding volume options causes `No such image` error.

Does anyone have solutions or hints for this problem?

Thank you in advance!

### Details

I'm using [redjack/mesos-master](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/redjack/mesos-master/) for master and [redjack/mesos-slave](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/redjack/mesos-slave/) for slave.

**Failed Commands**

Following command is for master.

```
$ docker run \
-e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log \
-e MESOS_HOSTNAME=<hostname> \
-e MESOS_PORT=5050 \
-e MESOS_REGISTRY=in_memory \
-e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/tmp/mesosphere \
-e MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos \
-v /var/log:/var/log \
-v /sys/cgroup:/cgroup \
-v /proc:/proc \
redjack/mesos-master:latest
```

This returns following messages.

```
Unable to find image 'redjack/mesos-master:latest' locally
Pulling repository redjack/mesos-master
e43e645e4613: Download complete
e9e06b06e14c: Download complete
a82efea989f9: Download complete
37bea4ee0c81: Download complete
07f8e8c5e660: Download complete
a170eebbd2bf: Download complete
104ab0553e3a: Download complete
d6f04b0daf32: Download complete
bdb0fee63b5c: Download complete
943ba7734c82: Download complete
e8b0687de36f: Download complete
9ae9def4d95e: Download complete
776c4db2701b: Download complete
63180ef60d78: Download complete
Status: Image is up to date for redjack/mesos-master:latest
FATA[0008] Error response from daemon: No such image: redjack/mesos-master:latest (tag: latest)
```

Despite the message above, image `redjack/mesos-master` exists

```
$ docker images | grep mesos-master
redjack/mesos-master         latest              e43e645e4613        2 weeks ago         1.092 GB
```

**Succeeded Commands**

As mentioned above it succeeds without `-v` options

```
$ docker run \
-e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log \
-e MESOS_HOSTNAME=<hostname> \
-e MESOS_PORT=5050 \
-e MESOS_REGISTRY=in_memory \
-e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/tmp/mesosphere \
-e MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos \
redjack/mesos-master:latest
```

**Environments**

OS:
`CentOS 6.5`

Docker:

```
$ docker version

Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): a8a31ef/1.5.0
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): a8a31ef/1.5.0
```

Comment: I have a doubt about `-v /sys/cgroup:/cgroup` I doubt /cgroup does exist in your container, you should check `docker exec -it my_container ls /cgroup`

Comment: Ah there's no /cgroup and I changed `-v /sys/cgroup:/cgroup` to `-v /cgroup:/cgroup`, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for user2915097, the problem was solved by changing `-v /sys/cgroup:/cgroup` to `-v /cgroup:/cgroup`.